# Heroku considers my app 'crashed' after idling it

Tags: python, heroku

My application is running on a free dyno, which idles after 30 minutes of inactivity. Upon receiving the SIGTERM signal from Heroku, my application exits with status 0 immediately. This roughly matches what is shown in the documentation on [how applications should respond to dyno shutdown](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#shutdown), which seems to be how Heroku 'idles' a dyno, based on the information in the logs.

The [Free Dyno Hours](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#dyno-sleeping) documentation states that "If a sleeping web dyno receives web traffic, it will become active again after a short delay". However, the next request to my app after going idle is served a 503 "Application Error" page, and an H10 error is logged.

Here is a log snippet of this happening:

```
2017-11-19T14:12:12.802576+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2017-11-19T14:12:12.803237+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2017-11-19T14:12:13.430011+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-11-19T14:12:13.436549+00:00 app[web.1]: wsgi exiting
2017-11-19T14:12:13.436584+00:00 app[web.1]: (4) wsgi exited, is_accepting=True
2017-11-19T14:12:13.659095+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-11-19T14:16:09.065549+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=[removed] request_id=5aa387f3-5d4c-42ab-a8cd-0f533888143a fwd="[removed]" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

Am I not responding to the shutdown signal properly? Why is Heroku not unidling my application?

I have tried running `heroku restart` as suggested on similar questions, but the issue still happens the next time the app idles.

This question is unlikely to be a duplicate of any question about H10 errors on dyno startup or after deploys.

Edit 1:
It seems idling and unidling does occasionally work as documented. From a few minutes ago:

```
2017-11-21T00:43:27.144020+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2017-11-21T00:43:27.144555+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2017-11-21T00:43:28.094439+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-11-21T00:43:28.251851+00:00 app[web.1]: wsgi exiting
2017-11-21T00:43:28.251891+00:00 app[web.1]: (4) wsgi exited, is_accepting=True
2017-11-21T00:43:28.511070+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-11-21T00:46:00.176638+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2017-11-21T00:46:00.176883+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2017-11-21T00:46:05.348372+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python wsgi.py`
[...]
2017-11-21T00:46:18.918352+00:00 app[web.1]: (4) wsgi starting up on http://0.0.0.0:4477
2017-11-21T00:46:19.251534+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

Comment: Answers to this question may no longer have an audience. The free plan has been discontinued, and I'm not clear on whether the new eco dynos are the same tech as free dynos once were.